# Deleting node in the middle and at the end

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I was simply wondering if the following is the right way to go about it deleting nodes in specific locations in a linked list.

> ```
> So if my "target" node is located between the head and the tail (middle):
> 1. set a "curr" node equal to the head
> 2. Iterate using "curr = curr.next" until curr.next = "target"
> 3. set curr.next = curr.next.next 
>
> If my target is located at the tail I do:
> 1. set "curr" node equal to the head
> 2.Iterate until curr.next.next = null 
> 3. set curr.next = null
> ```

I also struggle to understand how changing a "curr" node i set equal to "head" can modify the actual linked list associated with "head" and not just the linked list attached to "curr".

Thank you I really need help with this:)

Answer (score 0):

`curr` references the actual links in the linked list, not just copies of them, so modifying `curr` also modifies the LinkedList. This is because all java objects are passed by reference.

By the way I don't think thats the right way to distinguish the last item, should be like:

1. set a "curr" node equal to the head
2. Iterate using "curr = curr.next" until curr.next **.value** equals *target*
3. if target was found (the previous loop actually fails if target is not in the list)

   3.1. if curr.next is the last item: curr.next = null

   3.2. else curr.next = curr.next.next

This algorithm is more similar to real linkedlists because usually you don't know in advance if the target link is going to be the last one or not (or even if it's in the list)

Comment: With a slight modification (check curr.next.value instead curr.next) it would, but only if target is present in the list.